# Newly installed Airflow providers don't show in Web UI

Tags: airflow, provider, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I'm using MWAA and when I add new providers via `requirements.txt` they do not show in the "Airflow - Admin > Providers" UI, while the default providers installed on the MWAA instance show just fine.

**An example:**

1. I add `apache-airflow-providers-databricks==2.0.2` to the `requirements.txt`
2. upload it to the MWAA S3 bucket
3. wait for the instance to reboot
4. successfully run a test DAG to ensure the provider installed correctly.

**Result:** After all of that, this is the "Admin > Providers" tab:

[image]

I just want to be able to easily see all providers installed. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This might be related: MWAA running Airflow 2.2.2 is constrained to`apache-airflow-providers-datadog==2.0.1`. Reference: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.2/constraints-3.7.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like this is actually an internal VPC issue. I didn't think this would be relevant at the time, but when I run a public (vs. private) instance I do not have the same issue.

Comment: Anyone able to solve this one for private instances

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. As @theNewfelll said, this seems to be a public VPC vs. private VPC issue.

The thing is, if you enable Airflow scheduler logging in the Monitoring section, (edit and update the environment), you can see entires such as:

```
Installing collected packages: slack-sdk, apache-airflow-providers-slack

Successfully installed apache-airflow-providers-slack-5.0.0 slack-sdk-3.19.1
```

So, there isn't any error that the provider isn't installed, it just doesn't show up in the drop down list so you can't create that connection.

The issue is **Private web servers of the private VPC have no internet connection** - It's a shame that the log doesn't give an error rather than showing you it succeeded.

The solution is download the pip3 packages (slack in this example)with:

`pip3 download apache-airflow-providers-slack==5.0.0`

Once you have the .whl file, change the permissions `chmod -R 755` (-R = the hierarchies within the file, not just the file ) and then zip it (`zip -r plugins.zip .`), with any other plugins into a file called plugins.zip. Upload this to your MWAA.

The requirements.txt file needs to be in the form:
`/usr/local/airflow/plugins/apache_airflow_providers_slack-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`

As there is no internet access, plugins are copied to the plugins folder on the Scheduler and Worker file systems.